# Set Pivot Filter based on defined variable

Tags: vba, pivot, excel-2013

I have a macro that used to work in the Excel 2007, but after recent upgrade to Excel 2013 stopped working.
The macro sets a pivot filter based on the defined variable read from a cell value. Old code is below:

```
Sub test()
Dim PremState As String
PremState = Sheets("FormData").Range("PremSt").Value
Sheets("DataPivot").Activate
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("PremSt_A").CurrentPage = PremState
End Sub
```

I recorded a new macro in Excel 2013 that would do the same function. I got the following code example:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "[Range].[PremSt_A].[PremSt_A]").CurrentPageName = "[Range].[PremSt_A].&[CA]"
```

this works for the manually selected state (in this case CA), but I can't make it work with the predefined PremState variable.

How do I include reference to the defined variable in the new code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this...

```
Sub test()
  Dim PremState As String
  PremState = Sheets("FormData").Range("PremSt").Value
  Sheets("DataPivot").Activate
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ClearAllFilters
  ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "[Range].[PremSt_A].[PremSt_A]").CurrentPageName = _
    "[Range].[PremSt_A].&[" & PremState & "]"    
End Sub
```